# SimpleCov coverage generated using RubyMine with one tab

Tags: rubymine, ruby-on-rails-7, simplecov

MacOS Monterey 12.6,
RubyMine 2022.2.3,
simplecov (0.12.0),
test framework: rspec

Used simplecov configuration:

```
# spec_helper.rb
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

**Question:**
Why generating report with RM puts all in one tab? IS there any specific configuration for RM needed? Didn't find it in documentation.

**This is OK**

When running tests using command:

```
$ rspec spec   
$ open coverage/index.html
```

Then coverage report contains all these tabs:

> All files, Controllers, Models, Mailers, Helpers, Jobs, Libraries,
> Ungrouped

**This is not OK**

When running tests using command [from RM editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/code-coverage.html#b3a2e660) and after use button "Generate coverage report" (Saves in "coverage" folder)

Then coverage report contains only 1 tab:

> All files

In both cases coverage percentage is correct.

Comment: I tried it with simplecov 0.21.2 and the latest RubyMine 2022.3 EAP, but the results from Terminal and from IDE were equal and both were with one 'All Files' tab. Do you get it on every project or only certain one?

Comment: Checked also this project with simplecov 0.21.2, the same thing. In other project same.
@Olivia you probably did not use rails profile in this line: SimpleCov.start 'rails' ref. https://github.com/simplecov-ruby/simplecov#getting-started

Comment: Looks like it is not possible atm, got response on:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8257125921170-SimpleCov-coverage-generated-using-RubyMine-with-one-tab